# Debugging Javascript: Find out how a particular function was called

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am working on a web application with most of the code written in javascript. This application is using backbone.js and It has all kinds of event listeners. Some view functions are listening to model change events, url change events or user interactions. It's really hard to tell how a specific function was called. Is there a way to get the entire trace of function calls that lead to current invocation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a breakpoint at the start of the function in the debugger.  When the breakpoint is hit, then examine the callstack in the debugger and you can see the function calls that led to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug for Firefox will show the stack, once it stops in breakpoint you set.

Do you need the stack for debugging purposes?

Or, do you intend to use this information inside your code to make some kind of decision?

If that were the case, you could check the value of the variable "this".